# Devise: current_user == nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

My goal is to display the 'edit' and 'delete' buttons only to the user who created the listing. However, for some reason, current_user is returning nil. Any idea why this is happening?

Here is my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :listings
  has_many :thoughts
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Here is my listing model:

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :thoughts
end

<% @listings.each do |listing| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= listing.title %></td>
        <td><%= listing.school %></td>
        <td><%= listing.price %></td>
        <td><%= listing.description %></td>
        <% if current_user == listing.user %>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', listing %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_listing_path(listing) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Delete', listing, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
        <% else %>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', listing %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

Here is the create action in the Listing controller

```
def create
  @listing = Listing.new(listing_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @listing.save
      format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @listing }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my create_listings migration

```
class CreateListings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :listings do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :school
      t.integer :price
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `current_user` is `nil` when any user is logged in... are you sure that an user is always logged in that place?

Comment: Are you saying that `current_user` is **supposed** to be nil when a user is logged in? If that's the case, what command must I issue to address the user that is currently signed in? Not sure what you're asking me. @zeroed

Comment: If you're going to be doing a lot of this, and you're not already using it, you might want to use `cancan` in this app... https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

Comment: Thanks, @CDub, but are you sure it's compatible with Rails 4? It hasn't been updated in months, it seems.

Comment: A lot of people are using `cancan` with Rails 4…  Sounds like for 1.6 there are some workarounds that need to be done, but it might be worth checking out 2.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you have `before_filter :authenticate_user!` set in your controller:

```
class ListingsController < ActionController::base
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @listings = Listing.all
  end
end
```

As for your create method, so long as the table has a user_id column you just need to set the user for that listing:

```
def create
  @listing = Listing.new(listing_params)
  @listing.user = current_user

  respond_to do |format|
    if @listing.save
      format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @listing }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Lastly, for the listing to belong to a user it needs to be able to record that users id. Make sure your table has a user_id column:

```
class CreateListings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :listings do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :school
      t.integer :price
      t.text :description
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

You can re-run this migrate if it is your latest by calling `rake db:migrate:redo` from the console. 
If it isn't the latest you need to run the down and up specifically with `VERSION=xxx` to for that migrates ID (follow the steps here: [4.3 Running Specific Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#running-specific-migrations)). THIS WILL EMPTY THE TABLE.
If you need to keep date in that table then you need to write a new migrate with just the command `add_column :listings, :user_id, :integer`.

Comment: @DylanRichards The controller for whatever method fires the view code you posted (probably `listings_controller.rb`). If you don't authenticate a user in the controller chain then the `current_user` variable will never be set.

Comment: Can I just place it in the ApplicationController? I'm very new to rails and I'm not sure which of my controllers it belongs in. Furthermore, should I place the before filter inside the class? Or outside?

Comment: @DylanRichards You certainly can add it to the Application Controller, but this is a good opportunity to learn more about the chain that requests to your app follow. Your URL to the page your visiting will be along the lines of: `localhost:3000/controller_name/action_name` - if you have that structure, the controller_name portion should correspond to a file in `app\controllers`

Comment: If you put it in application controller it will filter every request on your site.

Comment: Okay, Matt and NickM. Thanks for hanging with me on this. I'm receiving an error when I try to create a listing now. It's saying --Can't write unknown attribute 'user_id'. What's this?

Comment: You need to add a user_id column to your listing model.

Comment: @DylanRichards Do you have a migrate file for the listings table? Does it include an integer column called `user_id` ?

Comment: @Matt - It does not. I have updated my OP with the create_listings migration file contents.

Comment: Well... I've run the migration again using the VERSION option. Now I can't sign into the site. When I click 'sign in', nothing happens.

Ugh. Might just call it a day, to be honest. Everything is an error in rails. How did you manage to learn this?

Comment: @DylanRichards Give it a little break then come back. I learned using a book! For this migrate follow the steps here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#running-specific-migrations and for a book check the info for the rails tag here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby-on-rails/info

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like`signed_in? && current_user.id == listing.user_id`

Comment: Also, Matt is right; you should include the before_filter in your controller.

Comment: You need to make sure your listing model has a column called user_id. When you create listings you should be doing something like @listing = current_user.listings.create(params[:listing]). current_user will be set unless the before_filter fails.

Comment: Hmm... It appears my create action in the listings controller doesn't have a user_id column. I'll show you what it looks like in a second. I'll update the original post.

Comment: @NickM You're assuming that Dylan is not using strong params... There is probably a method in his controller that follows the strong params structure considering he has used such a variable name.